# How can I tell if a given path is a directory or a file? (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm using C and sometimes I have to handle paths like

- C:\Whatever
- C:\Whatever\
- C:\Whatever\Somefile

Is there a way to check if a given path is a directory or a given path is a file?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Call [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(VS.85).aspx), and check for the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY attribute.

Comment: If you need to support Windows 98, then you can't use this function. See my answer about PathIsDirectory below if you need Win98 support.

Answer (score 127):

stat() will tell you this.

```cpp
struct stat s;
if( stat(path,&s) == 0 )
{
    if( s.st_mode & S_IFDIR )
    {
        // it's a directory
    }
    else if( s.st_mode & S_IFREG )
    {
        // it's a file
    }
    else
    {
        // something else
    }
}
else
{
    // error
}
```

Comment: the only problem I have with this code is the comment in the else case. Just because something isn't a directory doesn't mean it's a file.

Comment: @dicroce: Yep, true enough; fixed.

Comment: when I try to use this, I got "aggregate ‘main(int, char**)::stat s’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined" and really could not get what is the error. It gives error first in the line of  struct stat s;  What could be my mistake?

Comment: Okay, I needed to add #include <sys/stat.h>  my bad :)

Comment: is there an overload or similar function that support wide character path?

Answer (score 35):

With C++14/C++17 you can use the platform independent [`is_directory()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_directory) and [`is_regular_file()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_regular_file) from the [filesystem library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

```
#include <filesystem> // C++17
#include <iostream>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    const std::string pathString = "/my/path";
    const fs::path path(pathString); // Constructing the path from a string is possible.
    std::error_code ec; // For using the non-throwing overloads of functions below.
    if (fs::is_directory(path, ec))
    { 
        // Process a directory.
    }
    if (ec) // Optional handling of possible errors.
    {
        std::cerr << "Error in is_directory: " << ec.message();
    }
    if (fs::is_regular_file(path, ec))
    {
        // Process a regular file.
    }
    if (ec) // Optional handling of possible errors. Usage of the same ec object works since fs functions are calling ec.clear() if no errors occur.
    {
        std::cerr << "Error in is_regular_file: " << ec.message();
    }
}
```

In C++14 use [`std::experimental::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs).

```
#include <experimental/filesystem> // C++14
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
```

Additional implemented checks are listed in [section "File types"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

Comment: Hi @Roi Danton, thanks for your answer.  Do you know why this doesn't work on macOS?  It seems that it's related to Clang not supporting this library.  Very unfortunate, IMO.

Comment: @mannyglover Clang supports `std::filesystem`.Make sure to use Clang 7 or later with option `-std=c++17`. [Minimal example at compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/iCjzPZ).

Answer (score 14):

In Win32, I usually use [PathIsDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773621(VS.85).aspx) and its sister functions. This works in Windows 98, which GetFileAttributes does not (according to the MSDN documentation.)

Comment: I haven't tried it but the earliest documented version was distributed with Windows 95, so probably not.

Comment: You can certainly use `GetFileAttributes()` in Windows 98, and AFAIK it predates the existence of `PathIsDirectory()`. You can't rely on MSDN documentation when checking the minimum OS requirement of an API because MSDN lies! When MS drops support for an OS version, they like to remove most references to it from MSDN documentation, especially in minimum OS requirements of existing APIs.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you can use [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(VS.85).aspx) on an [open handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple method using the [GetFileAttributesW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesw) function to check if the path is a directory on Windows. If the received path must be a directory or a file path then if it is not a directory path you can assume that it is a file path.

```
bool IsDirectory(std::wstring path)
{
    DWORD attrib = GetFileAttributes(path.c_str());

    if ((attrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're using `CFile` you can try

```
CFileStatus status;
    if (CFile::GetStatus(fileName, status) && status.m_attribute == 0x10){
       //it's directory
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Easier to try FileInfo.isDir() in qt

Comment: Could you explain why to use a GUI library when a file system access is in question?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. (Via Google.)

Comment: why on earth did you 'drag' qt along here?