# How can i tell if a given path is a directory or a file?

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I need a C/C++ function like *os.path.isdir(path)* in [Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir).

I found a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146924/how-can-i-tell-if-a-given-path-is-a-directory-or-a-file-c-c) but i'm using Linux.

Comment: That [question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146924/how-can-i-tell-if-a-given-path-is-a-directory-or-a-file-c-c) contains a [cross-platform answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43281413/4566599) which also works with C++ in Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The POSIX solution is [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat):

> These functions return information about a file.

Basically, you hand it an instance of the `struct stat`, and if the call succeeds (check this first!) you get various fields filled in that describe the file.

You can then use the `S_ISDIR()` macro on the `st_mode` field to figure out if it's a directory. I suspect this is what Python does, under the hood.