# How to distinguish a file pointer points to a file or a directory?

Tags: c, file, unix, fopen

When I do:

```
FILE * fp = fopen("filename", "r");`
```

How can I know the file pointer fp points to a file or a directory? Because I think both cases the fp won't be null. What can I do?

The environment is UNIX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i've found this near by:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int status;
    struct stat st_buf;

    status = stat ("your path", &st_buf);
    if (status != 0) {
        printf ("Error, errno = %d\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }

    // Tell us what it is then exit.

    if (S_ISREG (st_buf.st_mode)) {
        printf ("%s is a regular file.\n", argv[1]);
    }
    if (S_ISDIR (st_buf.st_mode)) {
        printf ("%s is a directory.\n", argv[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `fileno()` to get the file discriptor for the already opened file, and then use `fstat()` on the file descriptor to have a `struct stat` returned.

It's member `st_mode` carries info on the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  FILE * pf = fopen("filename", "r");
  if (NULL == pf)
  {
    perror("fopen() failed");
    exit(1);
  }

  {
    int fd = fileno(pf);
    struct stat ss = {0};

    if (-1 == fstat(fd, &ss))
    {
      perror("fstat() failed");
      exit(1);
    }

    if (S_ISREG (ss.st_mode))  
    {
      printf ("Is's a file.\n");
    }
    else if (S_ISDIR (ss.st_mode)) 
    {
     printf ("It's a directory.\n");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If we decide to use `stat` family, why not use them directly? why an extra call to `fileno`?

Comment: @KingsIndian: Because the question is asking for it: "*... know the file pointer fp points to a ...*".

Comment: That *I have only fp, not filename* is applicable only if there's such a restriction (e.g. An API passes only fp, not filename). Otherwise, there's always a filename available somewhere. In OP's example, he does have filename. In fact, we can get two of `fp`, `fd`, `filename` if we have one of them (This is admittedly equivalent to what you have). But I doubt there's such a limitation in the question.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, Call [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944%28VS.85%29.aspx), and check for the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY attribute.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427436/how-can-i-check-whether-this-is-directory-path-or-any-filename-path) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146924/how-can-i-tell-if-a-given-path-is-a-directory-or-a-file-c-c).