# How to tell if a path is a file or a directory without elevated privileges

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi, filesystems

I have an process without elevated privileges, and because of that, I cannot get the File attribute of certains files/directories

```
const auto attr = GetFileAttributesW(path);
```

or

```
auto *pwfd = new WIN32_FIND_DATAW;
const auto handle = FindFirstFileW(path, pwfd);
```

In both cases it makes sense that I cannot access the file attributes, (because I do not have elevated privileges)

But all I need to know is if the `path` is a file or directory.

Is there a way of knowing if a **valid** path is a file or a directory without elevated privileges?

**Edit** It is not a duplicate of [How can I tell if a given path is a directory or a file? (C/C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146924/how-can-i-tell-if-a-given-path-is-a-directory-or-a-file-c-c), (for example), I already know how to get file attributes.

I am asking about knowing if the path is a file/directory without elevated privileges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell if a given path is a directory or a file? (C/C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146924/how-can-i-tell-if-a-given-path-is-a-directory-or-a-file-c-c)

Comment: No, it it not a duplicate, I mentioned `GetFileAttributesW` in my question. I am asking about elevated privileges.
It is not the same

Comment: Did you see this link: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/68935-how-to-test-if-file-or-directory/ ?

Comment: @SimonGoodman If you don't have privileges to access the path it is probably not possible.

Comment: what is error(better status) returned by `GetFileAttributesW` ? are you not have access to parent folder ?

Comment: I should mention that elevated privileges ("run as admin") are not the same as file access control.

Comment: how you at all get `path` ? the `GetFileAttributesW` can fail only if you not have read access to parent folder.

Comment: @RbMm, I get the file/directory from `ReadDirectoryChangesW`, when I get a modified action I cannot tell if it was on a File or a Folder.

Comment: what is error returned by `GetFileAttributesW` ? sharing violation ? what is error returned by `FindFirstFileW` ?

Comment: `FindFirstFileW` is more power here, because `GetFileAttributesW` can return `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` but `FindFirstFileW` will be ok in this case - all what you need - access to parent folder for read

Comment: @SimonGoodman Best you post a [MCVE] of what you're trying to do instead of having loong discussions in comments. That would probably lead to a good answer solving your actual problem.

Comment: @RbMm it returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, I should also point out that sometimes, (but not always), `GetFileAttributesW` returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` where `FindFirstFileW` is able to return valid attributes.

Comment: *GetFileAttributesW returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED where FindFirstFileW is able to return valid attributes* - very strong doubt in this. for `GetFileAttributesW` we need only `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access. but this is special access - ntfs grant it if caller have `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` access to parent. but if you not have this access - `FindFirstFileW` will fail

Comment: I just tested it and I get a few `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` from `GetFileAttributesW` if the file is in the temp folded, but then `FindFirstFileW` successfully returns the file attributes.

Comment: this probably because file is being deleted - somebody call `DeleteFile` but still exist open file handles. in this case any access to file return access denied error, but `FindFirstFileW` still able return valid attributes. but you say that in some case `FindFirstFileW` fail too. are also with access denied ? may be with file not found error ?

Comment: Yes, when it fails on `FindFirstFileW` it is for the same reason, `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, I ignore the file not found errors, (as I can no longer tell if it was a file/directory anyway).

Comment: also call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` instead `GetLastError()` (this api not enough informative) - i almost sure that you got `STATUS_DELETE_PENDING` after failed `GetFileAttributes`

Comment: `FindFirstFileW` fail with access denied (also call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` for more exactly info -really win32 error 5 not always access denied) -possible you simply have not read access to folder. you can check this by try open parent folder. in call `ReadDirectoryChanges` `bWatchSubtree` is true ? if yes - possible you really have no access to folder

Comment: so i strongly recommended call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` after file api fail. if it return `STATUS_DELETE_PENDING` after failed `GetFileAttributes` this mean that file is being deleting. this not related to any privilege. but `FindFirstFileEx` (always call Ex version!) still able get attributes, if file still exist.

Answer (score 1):

first of all `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` returned by `GetLastError` not always mean access denied error. usual (but not always) source of error - is `NTSTATUS` code, returned by native api and then is converted to win32 error code via [`RtlNtStatusToDosError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-rtlntstatustodoserror). but this conversion not injective. many different `NTSTATUS` codes converted to the same `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, not only `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`, as result frequently exist confusion about real reason of error. in case `GetFileAttributes`, `FindFirstFileExW` fail better call

```
extern "C" NTSYSAPI ULONG NTAPI RtlGetLastNtStatus();
```

api, instead `GetLastError()`. this is undocumented, but very helpful in some cases.

now about concrete `GetFileAttributesW` - we need have `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access to the file, for not fail with access denied. but file systems grant `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` to caller or if file security descriptor grant it, of if parent folder grant `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` for caller. of course if we have not both `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` for parent folder and `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` for file and caller have not [`SeBackupPrivilege`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/privilege-constants) (*This privilege causes the system to grant all read access control to any file, regardless of the access control list (ACL) specified for the file.*) - here nothing can be done.

but in concrete case i guess that op really got not `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` but `STATUS_DELETE_PENDING` error. this error will be if somebody call `DeleteFile` but still exist open handles on file:

> The [`DeleteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilew) function marks a file for deletion on close.
>   Therefore, the file deletion does not occur until the last handle to
>   the file is closed. Subsequent calls to `CreateFile` to open the file
>   fail with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

*(really of course NTSTATUS code will be `STATUS_DELETE_PENDING` in this case but `RtlNtStatusToDosError` convert it to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`)*

so possible reason, why `GetFileAttributes` can fail, is that file marked for deletion on close. but if file still not deleted, possible get it attributes via [`FindFirstFileExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfileexw). note - [`FindFirstFileExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfileexw) return information about file attributes in parent folder. for call this api we need only `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` access to the parent folder. this is reason why file systems grant `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` for file if we have `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` for parent folder. also `GetFileAttributes` can fail with error `STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION` if call it on page file (of course very special case). if we have not `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` access to parent folder (and no backup privilege enabled) - `FindFirstFileExW` fail too and here nothing can be done.

so possible solution, for not fail, when file marked for deletion on close - call `FindFirstFileExW` in this case. note that `FindFirstFileExW` much more expensive call compare `GetFileAttributes`, from another side situation when we query file marked for deletion very rare. so always better first call `GetFileAttributes` and only if it fail with code `STATUS_DELETE_PENDING` try `FindFirstFileExW` call.

```
NTSTATUS GetFileAttributesEx(PCWSTR FileName, DWORD* pdwFileAttributes)
{
    DWORD dwFileAttributes = GetFileAttributes(FileName);

    if (INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES != dwFileAttributes)
    {
        *pdwFileAttributes = dwFileAttributes;
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }

    NTSTATUS status = RtlGetLastNtStatus();

    switch (status)
    {
    case STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION: // this is only for pagefile i think can be
    case STATUS_DELETE_PENDING:
        WIN32_FIND_DATAW fd;
        HANDLE hFile = FindFirstFileExW(FileName, FindExInfoBasic, &fd, FindExSearchNameMatch, 0, 0);

        if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            *pdwFileAttributes = fd.dwFileAttributes;
            FindClose(hFile);
            status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
        }
        else
        {
            status = RtlGetLastNtStatus();
        }
        break;
    }

    return status;
}
```

demo code for test this:

```
ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x80;
static volatile UCHAR guz = 0;
PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
PWSTR FileName = 0;
do 
{
    if (cb < rcb)
    {
        cb = (ULONG)((PWSTR)stack - (FileName = (PWSTR)alloca((rcb - cb)* sizeof(WCHAR))));
    }

    rcb = ExpandEnvironmentStringsW(L"%tmp%/test.tmp", FileName, cb);
} while (cb < rcb);

if (rcb)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(FileName, DELETE, 0, 0, CREATE_NEW, 
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY|FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN|FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE, 0);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        ULONG dwFileAttributes;
        GetFileAttributesEx(FileName, &dwFileAttributes);

        static FILE_DISPOSITION_INFO fdi = { TRUE };
        SetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, FileDispositionInfo, &fdi, sizeof(fdi));

        GetFileAttributesEx(FileName, &dwFileAttributes);

        CloseHandle(hFile);

        GetFileAttributesEx(FileName, &dwFileAttributes);
    }
}
```